# Problema para posicionar a div

Tags: html, css

Pessoal estou com um problema para posicionar a minha div.
Não o que esta acontecendo em o que a div que queria colocar o slide esta em cima do menu. Como faço para colocar em baixo do menu?
Obrigado.

```css
body {
  background: url(skyblue.jpg);
}

.titulo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: yellow;
}

.subtitulo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: yellow;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slides {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ceja Feliz</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Description" content="" />
  <meta name="Keywords" content="" />
  <link href="ceja.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Título do site -->
  <div class="titulo">Mocidade Ceja</div>
  <div class="subtitulo">Entre aqui e ceja feliz!</div>

  <!-- Inicio de cabeçalho -->
  <div class="div_cabecalho">
    <div class="div_container">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="siteceja.html">Inicio</a>
        <a href="quemsomos.html">Quem somos</a>
        <a href="localizacao.html">Localização</a>
        <a href="faleconosco.html">Fale Conosco</a>
        <a href="eventos">Eventos</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fim de cabeçalho -->

  <!-- Inicio de slides -->
  <div class="slides">Aqui será o conteúdo dos slides, igual o curso do devmedia</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu alterei o css do `menu` removi o `float:right` e `margin-right` e mudei `margin-top` para `margin: 30px auto` para centralizar a div:

```css
body {
  background: url(skyblue.jpg);
}

.titulo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: yellow;
}

.subtitulo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: yellow;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slides {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ceja Feliz</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Description" content="" />
  <meta name="Keywords" content="" />
  <link href="ceja.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Título do site -->
  <div class="titulo">Mocidade Ceja</div>
  <div class="subtitulo">Entre aqui e ceja feliz!</div>

  <!-- Inicio de cabeçalho -->
  <div class="div_cabecalho">
    <div class="div_container">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="siteceja.html">Inicio</a>
        <a href="quemsomos.html">Quem somos</a>
        <a href="localizacao.html">Localização</a>
        <a href="faleconosco.html">Fale Conosco</a>
        <a href="eventos">Eventos</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fim de cabeçalho -->

  <!-- Inicio de slides -->
  <div class="slides">Aqui será o conteúdo dos slides, igual o curso do devmedia</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Como seu menu não tem um tamanho (`width`) definido, não me parece que você quer que o menu fique realmente na direta, mas se for o caso apenas adicione `width:100%` no `.slides` do seu código original e defina um `padding` no mesmo caso precise.

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil aceite-a como resposta certa no ✓

Comment: Obrigado chapa, obrigado mesmo! :)

Comment: Como estou começando a fazer um site agora preciso aprender mais como funciona as divs e os comandos do css. Você algum site para estudar os comandos?

Comment: @MellonFive [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender) em português e [w3schools.com](http://www,w3schools.com) em inglês